# stdout readline() blocking

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a minecraft server through Python 2.7 and it's working fine.
But when I try to pass it the stop command, it doesn't do anything until the server outputs something.

This is my code:

```
import os, sys, subprocess, threading, time

class Server:

    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def run(self):
        self.p = subprocess.Popen('java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui', 
            cwd=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'server'), 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
            shell=True)

        while True:
            nextline = self.p.stdout.readline()
            print self.p.poll()
            if nextline == '' and self.p.poll() != None:
                break

            if not nextline == '':
                sys.stdout.write(nextline)

            sys.stdout.flush()

    def stop(self):
        self.p.communicate(input='stop')[0]
#endclass

s = Server()
s.start()

count = 0

# keep running
while True:
    count += 1

    if count == 15:
        s.stop()
        print "STOPPING SERVER"

    time.sleep(1)
```

Image of output: [image: http://i.imgur.com/KgB3T9S.png]
I'd like to have it not pause there.

Stopping it after 15 seconds is to test if I can get it working correctly, but I have no clue how to fix this. I saw some solutions using 'fcntl' but I want this to work on all platforms so that isn't an option for me.

How can I make it so I can run any command at any time?

**Update:**

```
import os, sys, subprocess, threading, time

class Server:

    def start(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def run(self):
        self.p = subprocess.Popen('java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui', 
            cwd=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'server'), 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
            shell=True)

        print "started server"

        while True:
            outs, errs = self.p.communicate(input=None)
            print outs.decode()
        print "TEST"

    def stop(self):
        self.p.stdin.write('stop')
#endclass

s = Server()
s.start()

count = 0

# keep running
while True:
    count += 1

    print count

    if count == 15:
        s.stop()
        print "STOPPING SERVER"

    time.sleep(1)
```

Image of output: [image: http://i.imgur.com/U6RcE3K.png]

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: As I stated above. "But when I try to pass it the stop command, it doesn't do anything until the server outputs something." @Elisha

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

1. You are mixing calls to `.communicate()` and `.stdout.readline()`, which are both trying to read from stdout.
2. You are attempting to read from the subprocess's stdout on two separate threads simultaneously.

While neither of these things is *strictly* illegal, both are highly inadvisable and lead to problems like this one.

I would recommend having one thread monitor stdout/stderr (with `.communicate(input=None)`) and another manually talking to stdin (with `.stdin.write()` or similar).

Comment: Would this fix my problem, also how would I achieve that?

Comment: @user2900873: Change the `run()` method to use `.communicate()` and change the `stop()` method to use `.stdin.write()`.

Comment: Cant get it to work, I'm not receiving any output from the actual server. I'll update the post with my current code.

Comment: @user2900873: That's because you're still calling `.communicate()` in `stop()`.  You cannot do that.

Comment: I've added some pictures to my post so you know what I mean, thanks for the help.